# nginx reverse proxy as single entry point

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to use nginx reverse proxy configuration as a single entry point my home network.

If I connect to the root site https://my-name/ user and password is check with basic auth. Next a simple html table is shown with links to my internal servers/systems like:

```
href="/esxi"
href="/openmediavault"
href="/emby"
```

I tried with locations like

```
location /esxi/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted Content ESXi";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    proxy_pass https://x.x.x.x:yyyy/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

But this is not working. The defaule site with the table is always displayed. Path for ESXI site change from /esxi to /ui but not the ESXI site is displayed.

How can I setup nginx to proxy /location to the internal servers?

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to expand on "not working", including appropriate logs.

Comment: Not working specified. error.log and access.log shows no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You lack `proxy_redirect` for ESXi web-interface, so what's happening - your ESX returns a redirect to a new page, and your browser requests it from your nginx, but nginx has no idea where to get it since it doesn't match the location.
I suggest something like to start with

```
proxy_redirect https://x.x.x.x:yyyy/ui/ https://x.x.x.x:yyyy/esx/ui/;
```

But this needs some further testing and improvements.

Or you could use a simplier approach and add locations for every pattern that ESXi web-interface returns pointing at it with `proxy_pass`. This is indeed simplier but less elegant and skillful.